# How to turn off formatter for a single file in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode with `editor.formatOnSave` set to `true`. I want to turn off the formatter for a single file alone. Is there a way to do this?

I am using VSCode version 1.11.2 on Mac.

Comment: As of writing this comment, there is no way to do that. I have opened [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/33772) with VSCode to add support for disabling formatter for a code block.